# set-cookie header multiple times

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies

I have this code in a assets controller to get images:

```
function images($path,$image_name)
{
    $image = "../assets/images/$path/$image_name";

    if (file_exists ($image) && (is_file($image))) {
        $name = $image_name;
    } else {

    }

    $file = getimagesize($image);
    $filesize = filesize($image);

    $time_cache = 360000000000;
    $ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $time_cache) . " GMT";
    header("Content-Type: {$file['mime']}\n");
    header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=\"$name\"\n");
    header("Content-Length: $filesize\n");
    header("Expires: $ts");
    header("Pragma: cache");
    header("Cache-Control: max-age=$time_cache");
    readfile ($image);
}
```

I have set csrf protection to **`true`** in `config/config.php file` and every request for an image is sent with **`Set-Cookie`** header. So the csrf-cookie can get set multiple times on some pages. Is that something to worry about, and if so, is there a way to prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to do this with `header_remove("set-cookie");`

So the code looks like this

```
header("Content-Type: {$file['mime']}\n");
header("Content-disposition: inline; filename=\"$name\"\n");
header("Content-Length: $filesize\n");
header("Expires: $ts");
header("Pragma: cache");
header("Cache-Control: max-age=$time_cache");
header_remove("set-cookie");
readfile ($image);
```

Answer (score 2):

If in only one page/image request you uses `setcookie` function many times, php will send many times the same cookie to browser in one response. Maybe some browsers crashes reading that.

I've had problems with ajax requests in Internet Explorer due to multiple cookie definitions, when accidentally start the session object in CakePHP into a loop. I only detected that problem sniffing the connection with wireshark.

Comment: I managed to do this with `header_remove("set-cookie");`, Do you know if there are any side effects by doing it this way?

Comment: you will remove ALL cookies, even those declared by other components (or session manager), so you will need to redeclare all headers.. if you think to do this using something like headers_list, parse and redeclare at the end maybe works... i think its better (and simple) use a flag variable on global escope... weird but works, fast...

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, it worked for me, the session and csrf works, and it doesn't set new cookie for each asset.